# Оформление цитаты

Tags: прописная-строчная, пунктуация

На обложке буклета будет библейская цитата. Дизайнер обложки выслал макет, где она оформлена так:

"...и пойдут жители одного города к жителям другого и скажут: пойдем молиться лицу Господа и взыщем Господа Саваофа; и каждый скажет: пойду и я" (Захария 8:21).

Но у Розенталя четко написано: "Если цитата предшествует авторским словам, то первое слово в ней пишется с прописной буквы и в том случае, когда цитата приводится не с начала предложения, то есть в цитируемом тексте это слово пишется со строчной буквы".

Мое мнение, что оформить цитату на обложке следует вообще без кавычек и следующим образом:

...И пойдут жители одного города к жителям другого и скажут: пойдем молиться лицу Господа и взыщем Господа Саваофа; и каждый скажет: пойду и я.

```
                                                              Захария 8:21
```

Рассудите, люди добрые, время уже почти не терпит!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@Екатерина2012](/users/1088/%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B02012)](/users/1088/%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B02012), полностью с Вами согласна: кавычки не нужны, так как это эпиграф. И прописная буква после многоточия уместна и оправдана, хотя бы потому что выглядит более эстетично (по сравнению со строчной). Кроме всего, соответствует литературной норме, в частности по Розенталю.
Также источник *Захария 8:21* нужно разместить строкой ниже:

*...И пойдут жители одного города к жителям другого и скажут: пойдем молиться лицу Господа и взыщем Господа Саваофа; и каждый скажет: пойду и я.*

```
                                                    Захария 8:21
```

Answer (score 0):

Прямая речь оформляется так: *...и пойдут жители одного города к жителям другого и скажут: "Пойдем молиться лицу Господа и взыщем Господа Саваофа". И каждый скажет: "Пойду и я".* Но библейские книжицы вне законов русского языка (святой дух, видимо, не фанат Розенталя) - их пишут, как попало расставляя знаки препинания.

Comment: Кто я такая, чтобы редактировать библейскую цитату? Вопрос в том, как ее начать: с многоточия и большой буквы или многоточия и маленькой. И насколько на обложке уместны кавычки, ведь здесь цитата приобретает черты эпиграфа.

Answer (score 0):

Абсолютно согласна с ВАЛЕНТИНОМ. Поскольку это эпиграф, кавычки в начале и в конце фразы не нужны. Но дословно переданные слова какого-либо лица, которые содержатся внутри цитаты, всё равно берутся в кавычки.
Поэтому фраза должна выглядеть следующим образом: ...и пойдут жители одного города к жителям другого и скажут: "Пойдем молиться лицу Господа и взыщем Господа Саваофа". И каждый скажет: "Пойду и я". 
По-моему,уважение к Библии вполне уместно совместить с грамотным письмом.